# JQuery checking box on check

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page with several checkboxes, parent checkboxes and children checkboxes. There are two parent checkboxes :

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.parentBox, new { id="parent",@disabled = "disabled" })               
<br/>
@Html.CheckBox("_Commun", new { id = "common", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

My model is cut in two parts :

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool parentBox { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxModel> serviceCheckBoxes { get; set; }
}
public class CheckBoxModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
}
```

Now my children checkboxes are the following :

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.serviceCheckBoxes.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.serviceCheckBoxes[i].selected, new { name="child"});
    @Html.Label(Model.serviceCheckBoxes[i].name);
}
```

So that you have as many checkboxes as the model passes through.

I want to make a JQuery script that checks the parent checkboxes when I check at least one child checkbox, but I can't figure it out. Here is what I have tried :

```
var isChecked = $("checkbox[name=child]").prop('checked');
if (isChecked) {
    $('#parent').prop('checked',true);
    $('#common').prop('checked',true);
}
```

I have read that the `prop` method will return true if the checkbox is checked. I've tried using `.attr` method too but to no avail:

```
var isChecked = $("checkbox[name=child]").attr("checked");
```

Inspecting element on my browser, I noticed that the `name="child"` is not in the page, maybe this is the problem?

Thanks for your help :)

**Edit** HTML generated :

```
 <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Le champ parentBox est requis."
 disabled="disabled" id="parent" name="parentBox" type="checkbox" value="true" />
 <input name="parentBox" type="hidden" value="false" />   
 <label for="Lyon">Lyon</label>             
 <br/>
 <input disabled="disabled" id="common" name="_Commun" type="checkbox" value="true" />
 <input name="_Commun" type="hidden" value="false" />
 <label for="">_Commun</label>
 <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Le champ selected est requis." 
 id="serviceCheckBoxes_0__selected" name="serviceCheckBoxes[0].selected" 
 style="margin-left:20px" type="checkbox" value="true" />
 <input name="serviceCheckBoxes[0].selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
 <label for="R_daction">R&#233;daction</label>                   
 <br />
```

Comment: 1) Can you show HTML that is generated by your Razor code? 2) You have to run your code on child "checked" event - I do not see jquery code for it?

Comment: You do not have any checkboxes with `name="child"` (`new { name = "child" }` does nothing fortunately. Use a class name

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I will try thanks

Comment: Something like `$('.yourCheckboxClassName').change(function() { if $('.yourCheckboxClassName:checked').length > 0) { $('#parent').prop('checked',true); } else { ... } })`

Comment: But why are you disabling the checkbox bound to `parentBox`? It means that even if its check, it will post back `false`.

Comment: That's in my specifications :s I am remaking a website that is in production, and in it the checkboxes are disabled but checking the chlidren check the disabled ones ...

Comment: @StephenMuecke This does work though, thank you :)